# Make options accessible via camelCase and hyphens

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, naming-conventions, naming

Any thoughts how to make `JSON`-keys available with **lowercase**, **UPPERCASE**, **camelCase**, **PerlCase** and with **hyphens**. We've something like this object notation, which is declared with camelCase:

```
var options = {
    "fooBar": "foo bar"
};
```

But what is if the user declares the defaults with hyphens or similar:

```
var options = {
    "foo-bar": "foo bar"
};
```

How to access them then with just one key.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for example makes the keys in `$.fn.css` and `$.fn.animate` accessible with hyphens and camelCase

Are there already approaches for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made something, not perfect but it works so far:

```
(function(){
    var methods =  {
        toLowerCase: function(str){
            return str.toLowerCase();
        },

        toUpperCase: function(str){
            return str.toUpperCase();
        },

        toCamelCase: function(str){
            return str.replace(/(\-[a-z])/g, function($1){
                return $1.toUpperCase().replace("-", "");
            });
        },

        toDashCase: function(str){
            return str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function($1){
                return "-"+$1.toLowerCase();
            });
        }
    };

    Object.prototype.getItem = function(key) {
        var opt = this[key];
        if(opt) return opt;
        for(var method in methods) {
            if(methods.hasOwnProperty(method)) {
                opt = this[ methods[method](key) ];
                if(opt) return opt;
            }
        }
    };
}());
```

I've used `Object.prototype` to get the usage quite simple:

```
var options = {
    "foo": "foo",
    "BAR": "BAR",
    "fooBar": "fooBar",
    "bar-foo": "bar-foo"
};

console.log(
    options.getItem("foo"), // "foo"
    options.getItem("Foo"), // "foo"
    options.getItem("FOO"), // "foo"

    options.getItem("bar"), // "BAR"
    options.getItem("bar"), // "BAR"
    options.getItem("BAR"), // "BAR"

    options.getItem("fooBar"), // "fooBar"
    options.getItem("foo-bar"), // "fooBar"

    options.getItem("barFoo"), // "bar-foo"
    options.getItem("bar-foo") // "bar-foo"
);
```

Not perfect, but open for any improvements.